# the ModelMultipleChoiceField in modelForm not saved

Tags: django, django-views, django-orm, django-forms

I'm a Python/Django newbie and have been facing the following problem for several days now. I've got 2 ModelForms for a Model and the idea is that the data for one will help populate the multiplechoicefield of the second. The multiplechoice field for the second form populates ok but the problem is that the user's choices don't get saved. I've tried the `save(commit=false)` and `save_m2m()` but it hasn't fixed the issue.

models.py:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    asker = models.ForeignKey(Student, related_name='asker+')
    suggestedHelpers = models.ManyToManyField(Student, related_name='suggested')
    chosenHelpers = models.ManyToManyField(Student, related_name='chosen')

class QuestionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        exclude = ('chosenHelpers','suggestedHelpers', 'asker',)

class HelpersForm(ModelForm):
        def suggesthelpers(self, question):
            # populate chosenHelpers field according to data from QuestionForm
        class Meta:
            model = Question
            exclude = ('suggestedHelpers', 'asker', 'questionSubj', 'Qtext',)
```

views.py

```
def askq_page(request):
    question = Question(asker=Student.objects.get(user=request.user))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST, instance=question)
        if form.is_valid():
            question = form.save()
            # process data
            question.save()
            form2 = HelpersForm(instance=question)
            form2.suggesthelpers(question)
            variables = {'form':form2, 'qid':question.id}
            return render_to_response('choosehelper.html',      variables,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        variables = RequestContext(request, {'form': QuestionForm()})
    return render_to_response('askq.html', RequestContext(request, {'form': QuestionForm(instance=question)}))

def choosehelper_page(request, form='', qid=''):
    question = Question.objects.get(id=qid)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form2 = HelpersForm(request, instance=question)
        # here lies the problem- the data gathered from form2 is not saved i.e. the multiple choices chosen by user are not returned
        if form2.is_valid():
            question = form2.save()
            form2.save_m2m()

            helpers = question.chosenHelpers.all()
            for helper in helpers:
                sentQ = ReceivedQ(question=question)
                sentQ.student = helper
                sentQ.save()

            return render_to_response('questionsent.html', {'helpers': helpers, 'qid':    question.id, 'qtext': q}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    else:
        form2 = HelpersForm(instance=question)
        form2.suggesthelpers(question)
    return render_to_response('choosehelper.html', RequestContext(request, {'form': form2,    'qid': qid}))
```

Comment: Please format and indent your code properly, and remove all code that is not related to your question. Please tell us in your code where it does not behave as expected.

Comment: I've edited the code- I'm not sure whether the code is well indented though- I'd appreciate any tips/suggestions to try and solve this annoying problem :-)

Comment: I would really appreciate any help on this-even if only in theory- I'm at my wits end...